# Calculate geometry of Reference Point

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I have 4 placement points which I am using to create a outer panel. However, I have reference points which I want to use it for creating inner panel inside the outer panel. I have offset values available from each side of the outer panel. Now I want to calculate coordinates for the inner panel using Revit API/ geometry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please reformulate your question, this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to calculate new coordinates from coordinates and a specific offset, you're asking more of a Geometry question.  http://www.purplemath.com has tons of great information about doing those calculations.

If it's always a set (x, y) offset you simply add, or subtract, the x-offset to the coordinate.x, and same for the y value.  If it's anything other than 90 degrees, though, you'll need to start looking at the Y-Intercept Form and all that Geometry/Trigonometry math.